# several requests from one HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, request, httpurlconnection

How can I do several request in one HttpURLConnection with Java?

```
 URL url = new URL("http://my.com");
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects( true );
 connection.setDoOutput( true );
 connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 

 PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
 ps.print(params);
 ps.close();
 connection.connect();
 //TODO: do next request with other url, but in same connection
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the Javadoc:

> Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request.

The object apparently isn't meant to be re-used.

Aside from a little memory thrashing and inefficiency, there's no big problem with opening one HttpURLConnection for every request you want to make. If you want efficient network IO on a larger scale, though, you're better off using a specialized library like [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

Comment: I was about to say the same thing, about it not being meant to be reused

Comment: Have a +1, then! Usually I agonize so long over my answers that everybody beats me to it. :)

Comment: @CarlSmotricz may be true, ... but in my case I am getting to many requests, too many without any get/post parameter + 1 with get parameter, .... I have used simple code for httpconnection only.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017813/httpurlconnection-lots-of-requests

Comment: @Bhuro, this looks like a different case from what this question is about. I suggest you ask it as a new question!

Answer (score 3):

Beyond the correct answer, maybe what you actually want is reuse of the underlying TCP connection, aka "persistent connections", which are indeed supported by JDK's HttpURLConnection. So you don't need to use other http libs for that reason; although there are other legitimate reason, possibly performance (but not necessarily, depends on use case, library).

Comment: Thanks, but I've already done it with some third part library.

Comment: @StaxMan, I'm sorry, but can you give any example of implementing "persistent connections" with HttpURLConnection? Maybe any links or code snippet?

Comment: @Ksenia there's nothing to do there -- it's used automatically. It's transparent; new TCP connection is only opened if necessary; existing one kept open for some amount of time (30 seconds? there's some JDK default), closed if idle for too long. So your LOGICAL http request/response pair may use same PHYSICAL TCP connection as an earlier, completed http request/response.

Comment: A little more information on Java persistent connections from the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html