# How to Store output of API?

Tags: java, api, url

I am hitting API with this code-

```
 public static int hitUrl(String urlToHit)
    {
       try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urlToHit);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            int statusCode = http.getResponseCode();
            return statusCode;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Like this I am getting return value 200. It means I am hitting url successfully. But I have to store output of API. My API returns uniqueId.
How can I store the output ?

Comment: You are storing it, in `statusCode`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you explain the HttpURLConnection connection process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116961/can-you-explain-the-httpurlconnection-connection-process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String output= br.readLine();
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
URL link = new URL(urlToHit);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(inputLine );
}//while
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the response in a *stream* you can use:

```
InputStream isr = http.getInputStream();
```

and `call isr.read()` to get the output from stream.