# What is a java.net.URLConnection doing?

Tags: java, urlconnection

When I **connect()** to a URL. Is Java fetching the webpage as a browser would, just without displaying it?

I'm trying to understand for example, **if I were to connect to a Youtube Video URL**. Even though i could not see the page, is the URL Connection loading the page and playing the video as if from a typical browser (without the UI or visual representation of the page)?

Comment: It might help to learn how HTTP works in general.

Comment: It is very unlikely that this is happening. There is more to playing a Youtube video than fetching some HTML. You need a flash component or something equivalent to actually handle the video stream. I would indeed recommend catching up on web requests in general...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you explain the HttpURLConnection connection process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116961/can-you-explain-the-httpurlconnection-connection-process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fetching the raw HTML of the web page.  Similar if you where to open a page in your browser and right click->View Source.

If you connect to a Youtube page, you will get the raw HTML and within that code, will be a reference (href), most likely a  tag that points to the source of the video.

**--Edit**

A browser then obviously interprets that HTML into what you see on your screen.
A modern browser automatically connects to all references on that HTML page, as if loading multiple pages simultaneously, and putting them together.

Answer (score 2):

No, the URLConnection represents only that, a URL connection.  Using UrlConnection.openConnection() is connecting to the page, but it still needs to be told what to do.  It will provide you with a "printing" of the elements on the page only if told to do so.  However, it has accessed that file.  Connecting to and reading information from a page is a *multistep process*.

Please see the Oracle Java Documentation about URLConnections.  It provides a lot more information and clarity into how this class works as well as how to use it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html