# System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

Tags: java, android, security, ssl, https

1) I am trying to make HTTPS requests from Android mobile.
So I have created filename.bks file using below command

I have renamed the ssl certificate "load-der.crt" which I received from godaddy to "cert.pem". Then I used this file in below command

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -file C:/Users/Masthan/Desktop/BKS/cert.pem -keypass password -keystore C:/Users/Masthan/Desktop/BKS/keystore.bks -storetype BKS -storepass 222222 -providerClass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath C:/Users/Masthan/Desktop/BKS/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar
```

2) Then I have used this bks file in below code

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
final Context context;

public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();

    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

    // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore to the ConnectionManager
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
}

private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
        // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
        KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

        // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
        try {
            // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates.
            // Also provide the password of the keystore
            trusted.load(in, "222222".toCharArray());
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is responsible for the verification of the server certificate.
        SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);

        // Hostname verification from certificate
        // http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e506
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        return sf;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}}
```

Then I used above MyHttpsClient class to request to server as below

```html
HttpClient httpClient = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://xxxxx.co.in/");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

3) While executing statement "HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);"

I got this error:

```html
03-22 15:13:56.178  30079-30173/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
    03-22 15:13:56.230  30079-30173/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLNullSession.getPeerCertificates(SSLNullSession.java:104)
    03-22 15:13:56.263  30079-30173/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:98)
    03-22 15:13:56.312  30079-30173/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:393)
    03-22 15:13:56.353  30079-30173/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:170)
    03-22 15:13:56.388  30079-30173/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
    03-22 15:13:56.426  30079-30173/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
    03-22 15:13:56.469  30079-30173/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:379)
    03-22 15:13:56.508  30079-30173/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:580)
    03-22 15:13:56.545  30079-30173/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:503)
    03-22 15:13:56.583  30079-30173/com.revu.revu W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:481)
```

Comment: is it the same certificate that is used by the server using which you have created BKS?

Comment: I have renamed the ssl certificate "load-der.crt" which I received from godaddy to "cert.pem". Then I used this file in generating BKS file

Comment: I have used below code for my project hope that will resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
                    // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
                    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                    // From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
                    AssetManager am = getAssets();
                    InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(am.open("your_cert.crt"));
                    Certificate ca;
                    try {
                        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
                        System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
                    } finally {
                        caInput.close();
                    }
                // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
                String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
                keyStore.load(null, null);
                keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

               TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
final X509TrustManager origTrustmanager = (X509TrustManager)trustManagers[0];

TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
   new X509TrustManager() {
       public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
          return origTrustmanager.getAcceptedIssuers();
       }

       public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
           origTrustmanager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
       }

       public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
           try {
               origTrustmanager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
           } catch (CertificateExpiredException e) {}
       }
   }
};

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()); 




                // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
                AppLog.LogE(getClass().getName(), "Licensing Url is " + request.toString());
                URL url = new URL(request.toString());
                HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
                        (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                String line = "";
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    strResponse += line;
                }
```

Hope this will help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: I want to attach "your_cert.crt" to project and use it in BufferedInputStream. Is it possible. Becasue I keep "your_cert.crt" file at server.

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked for me. Now question is, this piece of code will it encode and send the data to server and decode it at server using private key??

Comment: Another question is, When I try to send or receive data, I need to use the piece of code which you have given. Will it slow down the communication between client and server?, because on every request to server it verifies the certificate.

Comment: yes that will be happen for all the httpurlconnection, because it is not keeping connection alive like in HttpClient. So on every url request it will do connection with the server and verify certificate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116961/can-you-explain-the-httpurlconnection-connection-process this will help you to understand httpUrlconnection in better way.