# javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection when are the request fired

Tags: java, http, https, httpsurlconnection

I'm debugging some method which is supposed to call a webservice and return the response.

Already found a lot of information regarding http(s) requests in these threads :

[[Can you explain the HttpURLConnection connection process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116961/can-you-explain-the-httpurlconnection-connection-process][1])

[[Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests][2])

Still one point is not clear to me :

**Would a request be sent each time one of this method is called :**

***connect, getInputStream, getOutputStream, getResponseCode or getResponseMessage***

**or is it fired only on first occurence of one of these method ?**

---

On my particular case, would this code snippet fire multiple time the request ?

```
URL url = new URL(webservice);
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {//blabla});

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

// As far as I understood : request is still not fired there.

System.out.println("callWebService : calling conn.getResponseCode()");
if (conn.getResponseCode() == 400 //Bad Request
    || conn.getResponseCode() == 403 //Forbidden
    || conn.getResponseCode() == 404 //Not Found
    || conn.getResponseCode() == 500 //Internal Server Error
    || conn.getResponseCode() == 501 //Not Implemented
    || conn.getResponseCode() == 502 //Bad Gateway ou Proxy Error
    || conn.getResponseCode() == 503 //Service Unavailable
    || conn.getResponseCode() == 504 //Gateway Time-out
    || conn.getResponseCode() == 505 //HTTP Version not supported)
{
    //handle wrong response
}else{
    System.out.println("callWebService : received correct responseCode ");
    isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
    br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    output = br.readLine();
    return output;
}

//close operations handled in finally blocks
```

Yes there is already much to say about not using a local int to store response code, to check only a few of these possible values and so on. This i gonna refactor anyway, I'm only interested in understanding if this request may be fired multiple times.

Comment: The request is fired once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this you may want to check the source code. Most of JVM classes have included sources, and java.net.HttpURLConnection does.

There is this snip in beginning of method **getResponseCode()** (as JDK 1.8_71)

```
/*
 * We're got the response code already
 */
if (responseCode != -1) {
    return responseCode;
}
```

So its cached. If response is still default value, -1, its executing request to server. But since this behavior is not described in JavaDoc for this method, I would not rely on this and use own integer variable.

JV