# Upload progress of files using HttpUrlConnection with multipart is super fast in android

Tags: java, android, file-upload

I am trying to upload files using multipart with HttpUrlConnection POST method. The files are getting uploaded correctly and I am getting the response for that. But when I am tracking the progress, it just gives all the progress in 1 second even for files >100 MBs. It seems like the progress is for writing the file to buffer and not the network OutputStream. Calling flush() on the stream after writing each chunk of data doesn't help. Seems like flush just clears the stream to network and doesn't wait for the response before writing the next chunk.

Here's my code for uploading the file:

```
//Initialised in Constructor
 boundary = twoHyphens + System.currentTimeMillis() + twoHyphens;

    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

   //This method is called to upload a file
   public String uploadFile(String fieldName, File uploadFile) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream()));

    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
            + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

    bufferSize = 4096;
    buffer = new byte[4096];
    long size = uploadFile.length();

    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

     while (bytesRead > 0) {
        int percentage = (int) ((bytesRead / (float) size) * 100);
        dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        dataOutputStream.flush(); //doesn't help
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }//This finishes in 1 second

    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server exception with status code: " + status);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Any help or explanation on this is really appreciated.

Comment: what are you doing with `int percentage`? i see only one place where it is created...

Comment: @pskink That is just used to calculate the percentage of the upload progress. It is not used currently because the progress itself is not working fine.

Comment: so why are you using `BufferedOutputStream`?

Comment: I thought it might help, earlier it was DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream());

Comment: yes, this is how you should do that

Comment: @pskink But that isn't helping either. All the solutions I have searched through are around this same concept and have same result. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: if you remove `BufferedOutputStream` your writes will NOT be buffered - just add some `Log.d` before `dataOutputStream.write` and see the timings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182084/discussion-between-ashish-kanswal-and-pskink).

Comment: I'm facing the same thing, found any solution? Thanks

Comment: @rob_ Not yet. For the mean time I have stopped working on this. Please let me know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Writing to the output stream does not actually trigger the network connection. The data upload to the server is done when you call `getResponseCode()` , as I have detailed in my other [ansswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116961/can-you-explain-the-httpurlconnection-connection-process/60349100#60349100)

Only if you have some way to ask the `getResponseCode()` to report progress, otherwise you have no way to monitor the progress.