# Single URLConnection to fetch only the first line in java using BufferedReader

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I am trying to write a Java program that should automatically download text from a website if and only if it gets updated. The problem I am running into is using only one HTTPURLConnection to do that because if i don't there will be billions of HTTPURLConnections to the web server since I am using a while(true) loop. Here is my work-in-progress, the getMsg() method receives a url and opens an HTTPURLConnection. Currently I am starting a new connection every time I have to read a line, which is not the most efficient way I am sure. How do I keep reading the same line with the same HTTPURLConnection?

```
// Starts a new URLConnection to "localhost/currentmsg.dat"
// Receives JSON string from the URLConnection
// Sets up a different variable for each object received from the URL for eg. if delete=1 means that the admin is requesting to delete a message from the screen.

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import org.json.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class jListenerURL {

// Current arguments retrieved from the URL
private static int msgID = 0;
private static int aptID = 1; // Apartment ID of current device
private static int unitID = 3; // Unit ID of current device
static String message; // Message received from admin
static int delete; // Delete a message?
static int dmsgID; // What message to delete?

public static void jListener() {

    URL url;
    boolean keepGoing = true;
    String msg = "";

    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.lotussmoke.com/msgtest/currentmsg.dat");
        while (keepGoing) {
            msg = getMsg(url);

            JSONObject jObj = null;

            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(msg);
            }

            catch (JSONException je) {
                System.out.println("JSON Exception for message, try restarting terminal.");
            }

            int current = jObj.getInt("msgID");
            int targetaptID = jObj.getInt("aptID");
            int targetunitID = jObj.getInt("unitID");

            // Keep listening, if the message changes meaning a different msgID then print that message
            if (current!=msgID && targetaptID == aptID && targetunitID == unitID) {

                msgID = jObj.getInt("msgID");
                message = jObj.getString("message");
                delete = jObj.getInt("delete");
                dmsgID = jObj.getInt("dmsgID");

                if (delete==1) {
                    // Delete a message
                    System.out.println("Delete msg ID? " + dmsgID);
                    continue;
                }

                System.out.println("Message ID: " + msgID);
                System.out.println("Apartment ID: " + aptID);
                System.out.println("Unit ID: " + unitID);
                System.out.println("Message: " + message);
            }
        }
    }

    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.err.println();
    }
}

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      jListener();
      }

  private static String getMsg(URL url) {
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String msg = "";
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String received;
            while((received = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(received);
                msg = received;
                }
            in.close();
            }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return msg;
  }
```

}

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us?

Comment: `if and only if it gets updated` updated means: if it's different from the last value you get from a previous request? P.S you cannot get something from a web page without connect to it.

Comment: Sorry, just added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply declare your HttpURLConnection object outside of your while loop ? It will then not open a connection at each call inside the loop.

Comment: I tried that but unless I disconnect the current connection and start a new connection the BufferedReader does not go back to the first line. It reads the line after the first line which is null.

Comment: Here lies the answer I suppose : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457538/several-requests-from-one-httpurlconnection

Comment: The problem is that I am opening and closing HTTPURLConnections in a while(true) loop which will bog down the server by quite a big margin. I guess then is there a way to keep on reading the first line of the stream using a class different than bufferedreader?

Comment: Actually there's no reason to fear that, your server should handle a large amount of connections. Just ensure you add a Thread.sleep(60 * 1000) somewhere, to request every minute for instance.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpURLConnection` cannot be reused, but it can reuse an open connection to the same server internally  by setting the header `Connection: keep-alive`. It doesn't make sense if you connect to different servers, obviously.

One way to efficiently test whether there are changes, is to use `If-Modified-Since` header or the like `If-Unmodified-Since`, `If-None-Match` or `If-Match` (see [HTTP Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header)). In this case the web-server decides to deliver a new document if there are changes or just sends the response code `304 Not Modified` without a body.

One last thing regarding the use of members (and especially static members): I'd refactor this code and the only item which would be left as static is `static void main()`. You can see the static members as some kind of global variables. Observing something like 'the connection is returning the same message' might be a effect of inappropriate exception handling and usage of static members.