# How to call External API in for loop

Tags: java

I try to call API with different id as shown in following code. But it only executed for first run and stop. Can Anyone help how to solve this problem?

The size of the idArray is 2.

```
for (int i = 0; i< idArray.size(); i++){
        String id = idArray.get(i);
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
        String myURI1 = "https://api.bulksms.com/v1/messages/"+id;
        URL url1 = new URL(myURI1);
        System.out.println(myURI1);
        HttpURLConnection request1 = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        request1.setDoOutput(true);
        request1.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authEncoded);
        request1.setRequestMethod("GET");
        request1.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json"); 
        BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(request1.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine1;
        StringBuffer response1 = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine1 = in1.readLine()) != null) {
            response1.append(inputLine1);
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `idArray.size()`?

Comment: Try stepping through your code with a debugger.

Comment: Why are you setting `Content-Type` on a `GET` request? Did you mean to set `Accept`?

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to refer @hgoebl answer to  [Single URLConnection to fetch only the first line in java using BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443228/single-urlconnection-to-fetch-only-the-first-line-in-java-using-bufferedreader).

"HttpURLConnection cannot be reused, but it can reuse an open connection to the same server internally by setting the header Connection: keep-alive. It doesn't make sense if you connect to different servers, obviously.
"